# Request to server made for script src="://0"

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have 2 different environments set up running the same J2EE application.  Both use Websphere for the application server and IHS for the web server.  Both are running the same version of my code and as far as I can tell are configured similarly (just pointing to different servers).

One environment seems to be running fine, the other certain pages are having problems, particularly where it has to make an AJAX call to fetch some data.  In the one that is not working, I noticed a request going to my servers for a url ending in ://0.  I do not notice this request in the environment that is working.

I have isolated the call to the mootools script:

```
else if (document.readyState && this.ie) { //ie
    document.write("<script id='ie_ready' defer src='://0'></script>");
    $('ie_ready').onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') domReady();
    };
}
```

I could not find ://0 anywhere else in my code.  I have no idea why this is being sent to the server.  I'm assuming something is likely configured incorrectly, but I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: What MooTools version are you using?

Comment: sounds like 1.1x see https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/1.1x/Window/Window.DomReady.js#L44